# Div appears within parent element's padding, not outside

Tags: css, flexbox

I've built a three-column flexbox layout and the first includes an image with a caption below it. For some reason, this caption (`.photo-caption`) appears within it's parent element's (`.card-cont`) padding, instead of below it. How can I style this caption to be pushed down as expected?

Layout sample:

```
<div class="card-cont">
  <h2>Symphonic masters 1 Subscription</h2>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-img">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2014-05/enhanced/webdr06/14/7/enhanced-21657-1400066093-5.jpg" /></a>
      <div class="photo-caption">
        Photo by Humberto Howard
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-info">
      <p>
        Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu. Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-links">
      <div class="button-cont">
        <a class="button blue-button" href="#">Subscribe</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sample CSS:

```
section.events-wide .card-cont {
  padding: 30px 0;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont > h2 {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 1.75em;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card {
  display: flex;
  height: 295px;
  background-color: grey;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-buy-button,
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-img,
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-info,
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-learn-more,
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-links {
  flex-basis: 33.3%;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-img a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-img a img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-info,
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-learn-more,
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-links {
  padding: 30px 2%;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-info p a,
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-learn-more p a,
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-links p a {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-info {
  text-align: left;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-info h1,
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-info h2 {
  display: block;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  padding: 5px 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-info h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-info h2 {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-buy-button .button-cont,
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-links .button-cont {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-buy-button .button-cont .button,
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-links .button-cont .button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Working demo: http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/jyBbEv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined hard heights that keep those elements from flowing naturally in the DOM. Removing the heights from `section.events-wide .card-cont .card` and `section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-img a` causes them to have a natural height that doesn't overflow content into the parent element's padding.

```css
section.events-wide header {
  padding: 15px 0;
}
section.events-wide header h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  line-height: 1;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont {
  padding: 30px 0;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont > h2 {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 1.75em;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card {
  display: flex;
 /* height: 295px; */
  background-color: grey;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-buy-button,
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-img,
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-info,
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-learn-more,
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-links {
  flex-basis: 33.3%;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-img a {
  display: inline-block;
 /* height: 100%; */
  width: 100%;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-img a img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-info,
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-learn-more,
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-links {
  padding: 30px 2%;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-info p a,
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-learn-more p a,
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-links p a {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-info {
  text-align: left;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-info h1,
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-info h2 {
  display: block;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  padding: 5px 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-info h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-info h2 {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-buy-button .button-cont,
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-links .button-cont {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-buy-button .button-cont .button,
section.events-wide .card-cont .card .card-links .button-cont .button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.events-wide.events-wide-alt .card-cont:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
.events-wide.events-wide-alt .card-cont .card {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.events-wide.events-wide-alt .card-cont .card > div {
  padding: 0;
}
.events-wide.events-wide-alt .card-cont .card > div:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right: 2%;
}
.events-wide.events-wide-alt .card-cont .card > div .photo-caption {
  display: block;
  height: 15px;
  font-size: .65em;
}
.events-wide.events-wide-alt .card-cont .card > div p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
.events-wide.events-wide-alt .card-cont .card > div .button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Events START -->
<section class="events-wide events-wide-alt">
  <div id="events-cont">
    <div class="card-cont">
      <h2>Symphonic masters 1 Subscription</h2>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-img">
          <a href="#"><img src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2014-05/enhanced/webdr06/14/7/enhanced-21657-1400066093-5.jpg" /></a>
          <div class="photo-caption">
            Photo by Humberto Howard
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-info">
          <p>
            Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu. Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-links">
          <div class="button-cont">
            <a class="button blue-button" href="#">Subscribe</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-cont">
      <h2>Symphonic masters 1 Subscription</h2>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-img">
          <a href="#"><img src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2014-05/enhanced/webdr06/14/7/enhanced-21657-1400066093-5.jpg" /></a>
          <div class="photo-caption">
            Photo by Humberto Howard
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-info">
          <p>
            Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu. Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-links">
          <div class="button-cont">
            <a class="button blue-button" href="#">Subscribe</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-cont">
      <h2>Symphonic masters 1 Subscription</h2>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-img">
          <a href="#"><img src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2014-05/enhanced/webdr06/14/7/enhanced-21657-1400066093-5.jpg" /></a>
          <div class="photo-caption">
            Photo by Humberto Howard
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-info">
          <p>
            Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu. Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-links">
          <div class="button-cont">
            <a class="button blue-button" href="#">Subscribe</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I see. I need these heights to keep the images at a 4:3 aspect ratio. Can you think of a way around this?

Comment: Never mind–I found a solution where I dynamically set the `img` height in JS. Thanks!

Comment: @MarioParra sweet! np.